# Find the biggest file in a directory and set the filename in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to find the biggest file in a specified catalog, and put the answer into a variable.

By using:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -1 it
```

It will find the biggest file, but it is scanning all sub-directories recursively.

How do I get it to scan just the specified directory?

And how do I put the filename into a variable? ($var1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict the search to the present directory use `-maxdepth 1`

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -1
5359532 ./coreutils_8.30.orig.tar.xz

$ var1="$(basename $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f  -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'))"
$ echo "$var1"
coreutils_8.30.orig.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try

```
#!/bin/bash 
biggest=$(ls -S -1 /specified/directory/ | head -n1) 
echo $biggest
```

$ **man ls**

```
-S     sort by file size, largest first
-1     list one file per line
```

$ **man head**

```
-n     print the first NUM lines
```

To include the full path in the variable, try

```
ls -S -1 -d /specified/directory/* | head -n1
```

however the **man ls** is unclear

```
-d      list directories themselves, not their contents
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you tagged the question `bash`, if `zsh` is an option:

```
print -rv var1 *(.OL)
```